# Can BMO$^{-1}$ be understood as the dual of BMO?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, function-spaces

An standard way of characterizing elements of the function space BMO($\mathbb{R}^d$) is by means of Carleson measures. Namely we can consider the heat kernel $\Phi_t(x)=\pi^{-d/2}t^{-d}e^{-|x|^2/t}$ and with it define a "norm" (not really a norm)
$$ \|f\|_{BMO} = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d, R>0} \left(\frac{2}{|B_R(x)|}\int_{B_R(x)}\int_0^{R^2} |f\ast\nabla\Phi_{\sqrt{4t}}|^2dtdy\right)^{1/2} \equiv \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d, R>0} \left(\frac{2}{|B_R(x)|}\int_{B_R(x)}\int_0^{R^2} |\nabla\omega|^2dtdy\right)^{1/2} $$
with $\omega$ a solution to the heat equation with initial datum $f$, i.e. $\partial_t\omega -\Delta\omega = 0$ and $\omega(0,\cdot) = f$.

Based on this definition one can also consider a new space denoted by BMO$^{-1}$ with a similar norm (this time it is a true norm) with one derivative less for the solution to the heat equation,
$$ \|f\|_{BMO^{-1}} = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d, R>0} \left(\frac{2}{|B_R(x)|}\int_{B_R(x)}\int_0^{R^2} |\omega|^2dtdy\right)^{1/2}. $$

We can also prove a correspondance between BMO and BMO$^{-1}$ because $f\in$ BMO$^{-1}$ if and only if there exists $g=(g_1,...,g_d)$ with $g_i\in$ BMO for all $i$ such that $f = \nabla\cdot g$.

This is all well known in Harmonic Analysis. My question is, I sort of understand why the notation for BMO$^{-1}$ because we consider "one derivative less", but is it by any chance also the dual (with respect to some topology) of the space BMO? The notation with the negative exponent is sometimes used to denote duality, but I don't see it straightforwardly here.

Comment: Intuitively the answer should be no, though to prove that in the strong sense (not isomorphic to) probably requires some geometric argument to assert that a BMO-like space is not isomorphic to a Hardy-like space. To be clear, though: I have never seen $\cdot^{-1}$ used to mean "dual." If you are referring to Sobolev spaces like $H^{-1}$, that $\cdot^{-1}$ is there because this space is the space of "derivatives of $L^2$ functions," so it's just tracking the number of derivatives in $L^2$.

Comment: @user378654 yes, that is true, but $H^{-1}$ can be also defined as the dual of $H^1$ or in general $W^{-s,p}$ as the dual of $W^{s,p}$ (not so straightforwardly though, there are some issue to take care of, see Adams' book on Sobolev spaces). But yes, I also get your intuition. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Just a remark: The dual of $W^{s,p}$ is $W^{-s,p'}$, $1/p+1/p'=1$ (under suitable conditions). So, in the case of $H^k$ spaces, the minus sign agrees with the duality simply due to the fact that $L^2$ is self-dual (and by Plancherel's theorem, or the like). Also, $BMO$ functions have "0^th derivatives" in $BMO$, not 1^st derivatives like in $H^1$ or $W^{1,p}$.